# the use of " link with "and " link to "

Tags: prepositions, verb-usage

> Thailand is linked **with/to** Peninsular Malaysia on the main land of Asia.

What is the correct usage of "link" in the sentence, **linked with** or **linked to**?

Comment: @Damkerng -- This seems like the perfect question for you.

Comment: Did the original poster mean "Peninsular Malaysia" (the part of Malaysia that is on the Asian mainland, instead of in the Indonesian archipelago)?  Or did the original poster mean the "Malay Peninsula" (which includes Peninsular Malaysia, along with parts of Burma and Thailand)?

Comment: What I'd like to know is which I should use "is linked with or is linked to" in the given sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few alternatives:

> Most of Thailand's territory is on the Asian mainland, but it also extends several hundred miles south along the Malay Peninsula.
>
> Kuala Lumpur is linked to the Asian mainland by the Malay Peninsula.  The southern portion of the peninsula is part of Malaysia; the central portion is part of Thailand; the west coast of the northern portion is part of Burma; and the east coast of the northern portion is part of Thailand.
>
> Peninsular Malaysia is part of the Asian mainland.  Peninsular Malaysia has a land border with Thailand.
>
> Peninsular Malaysia is on the Asian mainland.  Peninsular Malaysia borders Thailand.